# using 2 if statements vs if/elsif? Why one works and other doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a known concern with if/elsif statements?  I have issues and here is my example:

I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
 respond_to do |format|
    if @order.paid?
      #code here
    elsif @order.unpaid?
      #code here
    end
  end
```

But this will:

```
 respond_to do |format|
    if @order.paid?
      #code here
    end
    if @order.unpaid?
      #code here
    end
  end
```

with if/elsif...

I double checked all my if/elsif/else statements and made sure they all had ends in the correct place.   Double checked the order.order_status enum was either paid? or unpaid?

Not matter what, even if i confirmed the order as unpaid?, it would run through the paid? section and attempt to run that code and i would get errors because some params weren't there.  I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.  I assumed i was the respond_to (desperation) but wasn't it, tested and read nothing about interferences from research.

Once I changed it to 2 if statements, it worked finally.   It's not a big deal because an order can't be both, so either it's going to run one statement or the other regardless.

Is there any known issues with this?

My only other possible reason is the controller is VERY fat.  over 600 lines of code.  Yes, I know this is bad but it works for now and I will soon be attempting to push as much code as i can to the model once I complete the entire functionality of the controller 100%.

Could that be a reason? (doesn't seem like it can, but i can only think either it was the respond_to |format|, fat controlllers, or issues with if/elsif statements.

Comment: Please show what's in the methods `paid?` and `unpaid?`

Comment: I think the issue comes from those methods or your data, as in the first version you can only pass by 1 branch of the `if` statement, it always responds `true` to `paid?` so it never goes in the `elsif`, and in the other version it can pass in the two `if` statement so it  responds `true` to `paid?` but also `true` to `unpaid?` so it also passes in the second `if`.

Comment: but if there are just two conditions wouldn't you be better of just checking for `if/else`?

Comment: @Claeusdev there are more than 2

Comment: @adesurirey it's honestly way too much code to put here but inside there are payments methods for unpaid orders, when rate changes up or down for extra charges or refunds (when user updates shipping methods, updates cart before fulfillments, etc.), then if payment method completes, it updates the associated models, etc.  Nothing, I would think, that would interfere.  Is there anything on your mind you think could possibly interfere in any way possible?

Comment: @adesurirey When I noticed this code wasn't working was when I was testing unpaid? orders.  So shouldn't it just skip the first if statement of paid? and go directly to unpaid?

So a possible issue... The error I was getting (from code in the paid? statement, when testing unpaid?) was a "[] method doesn't exist", which the [] method only returns from a json response which won't get returned from unpaid?... Would that interfere?

So in an if elsif statement, is it running through the first if statement no mattter what.

Comment: But regardless, why would it even run that code is the order.unpaid? is true and order.paid? is false?

Comment: To clarify, paid? and unpaid? are both in the same enum so it can never be both

Comment: in your order model do you have something like a status property that is an enum? Something like `enum status: [:paid, :unpaid]`? Are you also defining `def paid?` and `def unpaid?`?

Comment: I only simply do enum status: [paid: 1, unpaid: 2] etc. ...is this not enough?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using an array (`[]`), not a hash (`{}`). Can you double check that? You can see an example of the syntax in my answer below

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Answer (score 0):

When defining an enum the simple syntax is `enum status: [:a, :b, :c]`. This has a problem that the names are actually only used on the Rails side but are simple integers in the database. If you ever change the order, you would change the meaning completely, ie if you added an option `enum status: [:foo, :a, :b, :c]` this would make all `a`s now be `foo`s.

The solution to this problem is to make your array a hash `enum status: { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }` if you made the change again, `enum status: { foo: 3, a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }`, this would now work as you expect, adding a new status of `foo`.